# PHP. Оптимизация изображений с помощью Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

Для оптимизации изображений использую PHP расширение *Imagick*, `Imagick::setImageCompression` устанавливает сжатие на изображение, в качестве параметра принимает одну из констант сжатия класса *Imagick*, вот они:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что означает каждая из констант, или какую из констант будет правильней использовать для PNG, JPEG, и GIF?

Цель сжатия получить изображение как можно меньшего размера без потери качества, или с незначительной потерей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой вариант — это проверить эмпирическим путем. Определите оптимальные для вас тип и степень сжатия по эталонному изображению.

```
$imagickSrc = new Imagick("test1.png");
$compressionList = [Imagick::COMPRESSION_UNDEFINED,
                    Imagick::COMPRESSION_BZIP,
                    Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW,
                    Imagick::COMPRESSION_RLE,
                    Imagick::COMPRESSION_ZIP,
                    Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG2000,
                    Imagick::COMPRESSION_LOSSLESSJPEG,
                    Imagick::COMPRESSION_NO
];

for ($s = 0; $s < count($compressionList); $s++) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $imagickDst = new Imagick();
    $imagickDst->setCompression($compressionList[$s]);
    $imagickDst->setCompressionQuality($i);
    $imagickDst->newPseudoImage(
          $imagickSrc->getImageWidth(),
          $imagickSrc->getImageHeight(),
          'canvas:white'
    );

    $imagickDst->compositeImage(
        $imagickSrc,
        Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP,
        0,
        0
    );
    $imagickDst->setImageFormat("png");
    $imagickDst->writeImage("test1_compressed{$s}_{$i}.png");
  }
}
```